# Calculating In Degree and Out Degree in a single query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I could use the below query for "In Degree" successfully:

```
match a=(p:Person)-->(q:Person{Address:'0xa1e4380a3b1f749673e270229993ee55f35663b4'})
RETURN count(a) as In_Degree
```

I could use the below query for "Out Degree" successfully:

```
match a=(p:Person)<--(q:Person{Address:'0xa1e4380a3b1f749673e270229993ee55f35663b4'})
RETURN count(a) as Out_Degree
```

But when I club both and write the query as below, then Cypher is giving the result of "Out Degree".

```
match a=(p:Person)-->(q:Person{Address:'0xa1e4380a3b1f749673e270229993ee55f35663b4'}),b=(r:Person)<--(s:Person{Address:'0xa1e4380a3b1f749673e270229993ee55f35663b4'})
RETURN count(a) as In_Degree, count(b) as Out_Degree
```

Am I missing something here? Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH (p:Person{Address:'0xa1e4380a3b1f749673e270229993ee55f35663b4'})
RETURN size((p)<--(:Person)) AS In_Degree, size((p)-->(:Person)) AS Out_Degree
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand that size worked but may I know the limitation of "count" here?  Does "count" not applicable for counting the patterns?

Comment: count is an aggregate function. In your query you are doing two aggregations successively (and in cypher there is no group by, it's done by the order).